# Concatenate cells and remove duplicates

Tags: excel

I have a data column in  Excel:

```
Block Name | Cultivar | Reporter | Pests 
| Pest Stage | Severity
```

many time duplicate the Block Name but different data in columns:

```
Pests | Pest Stage | Severity
```

I want concatename (Pests, Pest Stage and Severity by cells) and afterwards remove duplicates of Blocks,
the good example is attached in picture

Here is to image example [a link] https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATFLT.jpg

I hope understand me,
Thanks

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow — we expect questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems — but we will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us [what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: The picture uploaded depicted the results? There is no duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Insert new column and put formula to first cell in new column `=E1&F1&G1` and then remove duplicates in this columns

Answer (score 0):

**Steps:**

1. In Column I insert the below formula and drag it down.

   ```
   =B2 & "_" & E2 & "_" & F2 & "_" & H2
   ```
2. Select all columns (except headers), Go to Data - Data Tools - Remove Duplicates - Unchecked all columns except the one you enter the formula (ColumnI) and press 
   ok.